# Axios - blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to make a GET request to a cloudfront distribution (with an S3 bucket origin) through a React web app. The thing is, I think I already enabled settings on the cloudfront AND s3 so that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is included in the response headers.

Cloudfront cache behavior:
[image]

and S3 bucket's CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Response header when using terminal/curl for request:

```sh
$ curl -i -H "Origin: http://localhost:8000" https://<CLOUDFRONT_URL>/<FILE>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 260
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 00:42:27 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Sep 2020 04:40:14 GMT
ETag: "f59d5ad53f657ee2b8edee79703da391"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 28663e5849ed20a9d037ca8066957991.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: SFO5-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: I4t51yGLpfwqbS7QFSjOjuOH9UvxNaBjY8vuIbai53SzVsQ0to4Jaw==
Age: 38

<CONTENT HERE>
```

Response (and request) header when using axios:
[image]

As you can see, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing in the response header when it showed up for curl in terminal. How can I fix it so that the browser can make cross origin requests? Is it a good idea to use the cors anywhere proxy when I make an API request?

Comment: What do the headers of the response look like when requesting via axios? What request headers are being sent? What's the response like if you add `-H 'Accept: application/json'` into your curl request?

Comment: I edited the question to include information that you described. If I add the "Accept: application/json" header, nothing changes (it still works and gets the content)

Comment: I wonder if you're just getting a cached response - the Last-Modified at least could suggest that. Have you tried the steps mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/)? Have you tried doing a cache invalidation on CloudFront, then waiting for a few minutes for it to finish, then clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: What happens if in addition to GET on the bucket you allow GET and OPTIONS?

Comment: If I were getting a cached response, wouldn't the curl request also not receive the proper headers? Yet, it's still fine...

Comment: You are, in fact, getting cached responses as you can see `X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront` in both your responses from curl and the browser. Try invalidating the cache on Cloudfront

Comment: Hmm yeah. I invalidated the cache on Cloudfront, but the browser network tab still doesn't show "access-control-allow-origin" in the response header. I'm a little new to CORS, but I've heard its a browser security feature. Is chrome purposely removing the some of the response header?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't returned when you don't specify the `Origin` header (which seems to be the case with your Axios request). Also, by default headers get cached withing CloudFront, so if the first request doesn't have `Origin` set, the cached response will not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` saved either.